# PySerial: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, arduino, iteration, typeerror, pyserial

So I'm writing a program to adjust the speed of a rotating magnetic field. Basically, I'm just trying to send a float through the serial port to represent the user's intended speed. But I'm getting an error that doesn't really make sense. I've isolated the error in a much smaller portion of code.

Code:

```
import serial #imports PySerial Library

#Function allows for user input and conversion to float.
#If not float, "Invalid" is printed to the console, and input is requested again
def get_float(prompt):
        while True: #Main Loop
                try:
                        response = raw_input(prompt) #User inputs
                        return float(response) #Conversion is attempted
                except:
                        print("Invalid") #If conversion fails

def magnet_speed():
        input = get_float('Enter a speed in rpm to immediately change rotation speed\n>> ')
        print input
        arduino.write(input) #send to arduino



arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600) #declares which serial port the arduino is con$

magnet_speed()
exit()
```

This is the error if I run the script:

```
Enter a speed in rpm to immediately change rotation speed
>> a
Invalid
Enter a speed in rpm to immediately change rotation speed
>> 4
4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "magnet_speed.py", line 22, in <module>
    magnet_speed()
  File "magnet_speed.py", line 16, in magnet_speed
    arduino.write(input) #send to arduino
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 498, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 66, in to_bytes
    for item in seq:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

My only thought is I'm not returning the float from `get_float()` right, or I'm not defining the variable `input` right. The `get_float()` function definitely works alone to print the inputted number if I run it in the python shell.

Comment: it seems your arduino.write(output) need a iterable item. try arduino.write([output])

Comment: @galaxyan: serial ports deal in *byte strings*. Which are iterable in Python..

Comment: @MartijnPieters make sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`serial.Serial.write()` expects to be passed in a `str` object, not a floating point value. A `str` object is iterable.

From the [`pyserial` documenation](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write):

> Write the bytes *data* to the port. This should be of type `bytes` (or compatible such as `bytearray` or `memoryview`). Unicode strings must be encoded (e.g. `'hello'.encode('utf-8'`).
>
> Changed in version 2.5: Accepts instances of `bytes` and `bytearray` when available (Python 2.6 and newer) and `str` otherwise.

In Python 2, `bytes` is an alias for `str` (to make it easier to write code that is forward compatible with Python 3).

Convert your float to a string *first*:

```
arduino.write(str(output))
```

or use a different method to more precisely control how the float is converted to bytes. You could use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to control how many digits are put after the decimal point and / or if scientific notation is ever to be used, or you could use the [`struct.pack()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to produce a C-compatible binary representation for the value:

```
arduino.write(format(output, '.4f'))  # fixed point with 4 decimals
arduino.write(pack('>d', output))     # big-endian C double
```

what you pick depends on what the Arduino is expecting to read.

Comment: Thank you. It's a little more difficult to handle a string on the arduino side, but that should work!

Comment: @T.ZackCrawford: a serial port only sends bytes. I'm sure the arduino stdlib has ways of decoding a `double` value from a bytestream.

Comment: @T.ZackCrawford: I see there is a [`parseFloat()` function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseFloat) that appears to expect a string representation.

Comment: Oh, wow. I was assuming numbers sent over the serial port as strings couldn't be accepted by parseFloat().